# How to understand if a x-variable breaks statistical assumptions?

Tags: regression

In repeated measures regression, for each patient, we are wondering if : the number of cumulative measurements available for each patient and the time since the last measurements can be used as predictor variables.

Ex: On the 4th measurement for patient #123 ... num_measures = 4 measurements and time_since_last_measure = 9 months.

Number of Measurements: We think that this can be useful because the more you know about a patient, the more certainty you are likely going to have about that patient ... and this should somehow have higher weight in the model

Time Since Last Measurement: We think that this can be useful because the more time that has passed since the last measurements for a certain patient ... the more missing information might not have been picked up and produces more uncertainty ... and this uncertainty  should also be reflected in the model. For example, if patient #111 has 10 measurements but the last available measurement was 1 year ago .... and if patient #222 has 2 measurements, but they were both measured last week: logically, all things being equal, it would be easier to predict (more accurate) the next years response for patient #222 compared to patient #111.

But we are not sure if its allowed to have these kinds of variables because they might violate statistical assumptions. In theorie, these two variable could be related to each other and have multicolinearity ...and at least "Number of Measurements" variable is correlated with itself (ex: after the 4th measurement, the next value can only be 5) ... and as we understand ... x-variables can not be correlated with themselves as per stats assumptions of the model.

But maybe, Time Since Last Measurement is not necessary   correlated with itself (ex:  for the same person, the time at which the next measurement takes places could be random). Ex: In Poisson Distribution, the time at which the next bus will arrive does not depend on current time waited.

Therefore, how to understand if these two variables are allowed in longitudinal repeated measures regression?

PS: For Time Since Last Measurement variable, the first value of this variable for each medical patient will be 0

Comment: I do not understand why this question got closed. It is a perfectly valid question, in my opinion.

Comment: lol life happens!

Comment: As it seems!  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> In repeated measures regression, for each patient, we are wondering if : the number of cumulative measurements available for each patient and the time since the last measurements can be used as predictor variables.

Time since or between measurements can be of course introduced to the model. As for the number of measurements I would not be so sure. What research question would you like to answer by including this variable in the model? Whether the number of measured variables explains the variability in the observed data, or whether more measurements provide more accurate results? Unless this is some quantum-nuclear-medicine problem I would not add the number of variables to the model. If you wish to check what number of parameters is optimal (or most economical) for your model, there are other ways of investigating this issue, e.g., from the statistical perspective, by using AIC ratio.

> Number of Measurements: We think that this can be useful because the more you know about a patient, the more certainty you are likely going to have about that patient ... and this should somehow have higher weight in the model

The "somehow" is the key word here: but how exactly? Usually it is better to take as few measurements as possible, for the comport of the patient, the clinician, and because of the economical reality of the healthcare. E.g., if you are measuring temperature once, with a proper quality thermometer, you should get best result on the first try, hence there is no need for further testing. If you are conducting an experiment, you specify exactly how many measurements you will have for each patient, so you do not get 100 measurement for one, and 5 for the other. I always look at data analysis from the perspective of performing a scientific experiment (often within an ex post facto model, i.e., as a retrospective analysis). If you end up with different number of measurements per patient you can always aggregate or normalize your data and carry on with a unified number of measurements (i.e., levels of a ordinal/nominal variable "time").

> In theorie, these two variable could be related to each other and have multicolinearity ...and at least "Number of Measurements" variable is correlated with itself (ex: after the 4th measurement, the next value can only be 5) .

Good observation, yet another reason for not doing it.

> "repeated measures regression"

Again, I strongly suggest you did some (re)reading on statistical models in general (I do it myself from time to time, as a reminder). A repeated measures experiment is a very strict procedure, and usually, the description of such model already provides you with definite answers to the majority of the doubts you can be having about the analysis.

To sum up, you raised a very intriguing issue, yet, in my understanding and the interpretation of the currently utilized theoretical framework for performing analyses (in a post-experiment like fashion), I believe that number of measurements should not be treated as an X (independent) variable. Unless, of course, you are yet studying the accuracy of some medical device, or something. E.g., you are checking the variability of measurements of a thermometer by performing hundreds of repetition. But I would not call it an experiment then, really, for the reasons explained above (as usually, in traditional physics, number of observations should not interact with the ontology of the observed phenomena or object).

I hope you got a different perspective on the problem, and it helps your research plan. Good luck with your analyses, bye.